# Confusing error message "Expected type unit but was X"

Tags: f#

I'm either not seeing something obvious or just generally confused
The code I have looks like:

```
let inline createContext source destination  =
    let src = (fun amount (s:^T) -> (^T : (member DecreaseBalance : decimal -> ^a) (s, amount)))
    let dst = (fun amount (d:^T) -> (^T : (member IncreaseBalance : decimal -> ^a) (d, amount)))
    let log = (fun msg a -> (^T : (member LogMessage : string -> ^a) (a, msg)))
    let f = fun amount -> src amount source |> ignore
                          log "" source |> ignore
    let f = fun amount -> dst amount destination |> ignore
                          log "" destination |> ignore
    new Context (source, destination, src, dst, log)
let src = new Account(0m)
let dst = new Account(0m)
let ctxt = createContext src dst
```

The type Account fullfils the member constraints of createContext. Intellisense claims the signartur of createContext to be Account -> Account -> Context but the compiler complains at src in the last line with "This expression was expected to have type     unit     but here has type     Account"
Any idea of what I'm missing?

If I rename a member function of Account so it no longer meets the constraints I get
"The type 'Account' does not support any operators named 'LogMessage'" which is what I would expect in that scenario. I get the same error message if I pass () as the first argument. That unit doesn't support LogMessage (not that it would bring me any good if that actually compiled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles fine for me, given the following types

```
type Context(a, b, c, d, e) = class end
type Account(a) = 
  member __.DecreaseBalance(a) = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
  member __.IncreaseBalance(a) = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
  member __.LogMessage(a) = Unchecked.defaultof<_>
```

I suspect something else is going on. Can you show more of the code?

It's strange that `createContext` is inferred to be `Account -> Account -> Context`. I would expect `'T -> 'T -> Context ('T requires member DecreaseBalance and IncreaseBalance and LogMessage`). That may or may not be a clue to your problem.

If possible, replace the static member constraints with an interface.

Comment: Replacing with an interface is not an option. This is an excercise to avoid explicit interfaces. (it's a result of a debat on a google group: object-composition)

Comment: The code is a bit confusing. `f` is defined twice--both definitions are unused. Maybe seeing the definitions of `Context` and `Account` would clear things up.

Comment: f is deliberately unused. The definitions of f is to test if source and destination fullfils the constraint which will be used later. Yes it's a bit weird but it's more about proving properties of strongly typed languages than anything else. You did put me on the right track. I had a wrong indentation in Context

Comment: In more detail src was used in an expression that due to bad indentation returned unit. The error message was wrong and on the wrong line. A warning that I was throwing a way the return value would have been what I'd expected